# How can I get two buttons to display in line?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have two buttons `Update` and `Cancel` which I want to display side-by-side.

However there's a break between the two buttons (see image attached).

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="form_block span2">
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" style="display:inline;"/> 
    <a class="btn btn-danger" style="display:inline;" href="{% url profile_detail profile.user.username %}">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

How can I get the two buttons to display side by side?

Comment: in the current state of your code they have to be side by side.. maybe your containing `div` is really narrow?

Comment: Since you didn't include the CSS, it's impossible to tell.  Why don't you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks @ZoltanToth that was the problem

Comment: If you right a response I'll accept it. Might be helpful to others?

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons in an `<ul>` element and each button in a `<li>` element with `style="display:inline"`

example code:

```
<style>
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li
{
display:inline;
 }
 </style>

 <div class="form_block span2"><br>
    <ul>
      <li><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" /></li>
      <li><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url profile_detail profile.user.username %}">Cancel</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```